# Does an AngularJS watch fire upon object initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm currently working on an AngularJS app

I have an object which contains some boolean flags. I created a watch for one of such bool.

Does the watch fire upon object creation? Can the watch fire at random time even the boolean flag hasn't changed?

Comment: paste some code

Comment: @Hitmands I'll do. But I was asking the general behavior. Does my question make any sense?

Comment: The watch is fired at init. So you have to check for newValue !== oldValue.

Comment: Yes, it always get fire when you change object reference, but again it dependence which type of watch you have. Could you please add some code here?

Comment: @PankajParkar please have a look at the answer below

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek please have a look at the answer below

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini just edited the answer and added the oldValue, newValue check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have (I'm working with Gianluca):

```
scope.$watch("chartData.selectedIndicator", function() {
    if (chartData.selectedIndicator !== -1){
        highlightMessageIndicator(chartData.selectedIndicator);
    }
}, true);
```

...despite not having updated chartData.selectedIndicator, this watch is still being hit and I am wondering if it is because within our chartData factory we are initialising selectedIndicator and this is why the watch is being hit?

```
angular
    .module("app")
    .factory("chartData", [..., chartData]);

function chartData(...) {
    var chartData = {
        selectedIndicator   : -1,
```

I wonder if this would potentially be a case of just checking for newValue !== oldValue as suggested then?